# vsftp on CentOS - unable to get a folder list of /var directory

Tags: centos, ftp

I'm just getting started with CentOS and running into a strange issue with vsftp.  When I FTP in, then change directory to /var I don't get a folder list.  Is there something about CentOS or vsftp in particular that I may be missing that causes this behavior?

The permissions on the folder are like others that I am able to see while connected via FTP.

Thanks for any help.

Evan

Comment: Is your install of vsftpd chrooted by default?

Comment: All the chroot stuff is left commented out, which means users should not be taken to their home dir by default (as far as i can tell at least)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is AppArmor or SELinux installed on the machine? Setting the correct security settings with those programs may be preventing any action.

Comment: I haven't installed either of those, so unless they come with the default CentOS 5.3 install, no.

Comment: http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux It appears that it does come with SELinux. It was first introduced in CentOS 4.

Comment: Ahh I see, I will take a look and see what I can turn up there.  Any idea where I might look? Thanks.

Comment: Yup, it was SELinux after all.  Thank you!  This was the additional step that I needed:
/usr/sbin/setsebool -P ftp_home_dir=1

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/vsftpd-and-selinux-449313/